# command: calabash-android setup. Как использовать данную команду с статичными параметрами "path", "password", "alias"?

Tags: android, bash, shell, тестирование, test-automation

`calabash-android setup` - команда которая указывает `путь`, `пароль` и `alias` файла `.keystore` для конкретного билда `.apk`

Когда я использую эту команду в командной строке ОС Linux, я хочу чтобы отправлялись статические параметры `"path"`, `"password"`, `"alias"`. Это нужно для моего bash скрипта, мой скрипт генерирует `.keystore` файл и использует в дальнейшем аргументы `"path"`, `"password"`, `"alias"` в команде `calabash-android setup`

Как отправить статические параметры  `"path"`, `"password"`, `"alias"`?

```
calabash-android setup "path", "password", "alias"
```

---

Для справки, что такое этот calabash-android:

- http://calaba.sh/
- https://habrahabr.ru/post/219655/

Comment: Прошу прощения, это был мой первый пост на stackoverflow

Comment: Вы все еще можете его отредактировать.

Comment: Отформатировал. Всё равно суть задачи не очень понятна. Вы хотите передать параметры в функцию на shell?

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что ваш скрипт запускается в процессе выполнения команды `calabash-android setup`?

Comment: Нет, мой скрипт запускается с помощью исполняемого файла, в моем случае командой 2dev.sh, далее следует порядок команд который я указал в исполняемом файле 2dev.sh и одна из команд calabash-android setup my.apk

Comment: @grinpic, `2dev.sh` — это и есть упоминаемый вами «bash скрипт»?

Comment: да, в данном файле содержится bash скрипт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я решил проблему другим способом, дело в том что команда calabash-android setup my.apk записывает в /.calabash_settings параметры и вроде как больше ничего, я убрал из своего скрипта команду calabash-android setup и сделал перезапись /.calabash_settings добавляя нужные и заранее сохраненные мною переменные в параметры.

```
static_param="{\"keystore_location\":\"$path\",\"keystore_password\":\"$password\",\"keystore_alias\":\"$randomalias\"}"
echo $static_param > /.calabash_settings
```

Теперь тесты запускаются! Большое всем спасибо!

Comment: Тут не работает синтаксис `<code></code>`. Вместо него просто сделайте отступ в 4 пробела.

Comment: Хорошо, буду знать!